# How extract parameters passed by delegate parameter

Tags: c#, parameters, delegates, helper

I try to build a helper in MVC. I try passed parameters like this:

```
@Html.InputHandler(settings =>
{
    settings.Name = "Julio";
    settings.Mask = "000-000-000";
    settings.visible = false;
    settings.Label = true;
    settings.htmlAttributes = new { @class="form-control" }
})
```

I have the following code for definition of parameters

```
public delegate void Action<in T>(T obj);

public class InputSettings : SettingsBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Label { get; set; }
    public string Binding { get; set; }
    public bool visible { get; set; }
    public object htmlAttributes { get; set; }
    public string Mask { get; set; }
}
```

the problem is I can not get values passed from the helper

```
public static MvcHtmlString InputHandler(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, Action<InputSettings> method)
    {
        var parameters = method. ???        
        return new MvcHtmlString("");
    }
```

Thank's!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to retrieve the body (since it would have been compiled and JIT'ed away into a much different state by the time you tried to retrieve it), you would need an `Expression<Action<T>>`.  However, you cannot convert lambda statement bodies to expression trees.  As a result, you may be better off passing in a strongly typed object as a Func and pulling back the results immediately.

```
void Main()
{
    InputHandler(() => new InputSettings {
        Name = "Test1",
        Mask = "test mask"
    }); 
}

public static MvcHtmlString InputHandler(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
    Func<InputSettings> method)
{
    var parameters = method();        
    return new MvcHtmlString("");
}
```